# Placeholder.js Append water mark as Text in Textbox control, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

[image]

In IE-9 If textbox leave black and allowed to search the water water

**"Request Type"**

append to query as search criteria, any fix for placeholder.js that ignores watermark text

working perfectly in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

IE-9 does not determines placeholder. As I understand - its your problem. So if you need to use it in IE-9 you can get it something like this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="E-mail-1">
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="E-mail-2">
<input type="text" value="Value" placeholder="E-mail-3">
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.placeholdr { color: gray }
</style>
```

Its code on JS without JQuery:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function setPlaceHolders(){
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); // get all text fields
var cls = "placeholdr"; // set name of the class

if (input) { // if fields found
    for (var i=0; i < input.length; i++) { 
        var t = input[i]; 
        var txt = t.getAttribute("placeholder");

        if (txt.length > 0) { // if placeholder found
            t.className = t.value.length == 0 ? t.className+" "+cls : t.className; // add class
            t.value = t.value.length > 0 ? t.value : txt; // if no value found

            t.onfocus = function() { // on focus
                this.className = this.className.replace(cls);
                this.value = this.value == this.getAttribute("placeholder") ? "" : this.value;
            }

            t.onblur = function() { // on focus out 
                if (this.value.length == 0) {
                    this.value = this.getAttribute("placeholder");
                    this.className = this.className+" "+cls; // add class
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
})();
</script>
<![endif]-->
```